# Как вывести экземпляры пользовательских типов в шаблонной странице wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленным [плагином Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) для вывода пользовательских постов. Создаю новый тип с именем `test`, в который добавляю текстовое поле `test_text` и создаю экземпляр этого типа уже с бокового меню.
Теперь у меня вопрос: как вывести экземпляры этих типов с полем на странице шаблона

```
<div><?php $text = pods('test');
echo $text->field('test_text');?></div>
```

`$text` объект получает (вижу через var_dump), но поле не выводит - почему?
Прикладываю скриншоты:
[image: фото 1]
[image: фото 2]
[image: фото 3]
[image: фото 4]
затем внутри файла `index.php` прописываю:

```
<span><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_text', true) ?></span>
```

в `span` пусто..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

`<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_text', true) ?>`

Вот как это выглядело в проекте:

```
            <div class="catalog wrap" data-block="2">
                <h2><?php echo $brief_catalogue; ?></h2>
                <ul>
                    <?php $currentPage = $post ?>
                    <?php $smesi = new WP_Query([
                        'post_type'     => 'smesi',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                        'order'         => 'ASC'
                    ]); ?>
                    <?php $i = 1 ?>
                    <?php while($smesi->have_posts()): ?>
                        <?php $smesi->the_post(); ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_ID())?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" ?>
                                    <div class="product-item">
                                        <div class="img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <h3><?php echo html_entity_decode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'info_name', true)) ?></h3>
                                            <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'info_description', true) ?></p>

                                            <div class="button">Подробнее</div>
                                            <div class="price"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'info_price', true) ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <?php endwhile ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
                    <?php $post = $currentPage  ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: а где узнать get_the_ID() ? ожидаемо ничего не выводит

Comment: у меня все отработало, get_the_ID() само подтянется с вашей страницы. Я специально для этого поставил Pods, создал такой же CPT и вывел его содержимое

Comment: давайте смотреть - специально в описание добавил скрины - у вас так?

Comment: А причем здесь index.php, если вы регистрируете custom-post-type? Если я не ошибаюсь в таком случае Вам нужно сделать вывод постов в цикле и там вывести этот код. Если сейчас вспомню в каком проекте я это делал, покажу пример

Comment: Вот на этом [тестовом сайте](http://e95812ga.bget.ru/test/test-page/) выводится текст `Some text description` благодаря этому коду `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_text', true) ?>` указанному в шаблоне single.php. В ответе на Ваш вопрос я добавил код, который был в проекте выведен в index.php

Comment: спасибо, как награда будет доступна - я назначу вам. единственные пока еще вопрос остался с полем галлереи - их выводит даже `var_dump` в виде `array`

Answer (score 1):

Функция `get_theID()` возвращает ID текущего объекта в основном или пользовательском цикле. В примере от @eugene_v текущий объект (пост) устанавливается вызовом `$smesi->the_post();`. Вам же нужно взять ID из экземпляра `pods`, а именно что-то вроде `$text->id;` (точно не знаю, смотрите исходники)