# Как сохранить и вывести контент в созданном виджете wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, плагин, виджет

Сайт на **wordpress** с установленным [плагином advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). Есть необходимость создать собственный виджет, в который включить некоторые поля из **advanced custom fields**.
Виджет создаю таким образом, включаю в него произвольные поля (вывод картинки)

```
    class CustomWidget extends WP_Widget {
      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
          'custom_widget', // Base ID
          __('CustomWidget', 'text_domain'), // Name
          array( 'description' => __( 'Some CustomWidget', 'text_domain' ), ) 
        );
      } // widget actual processes
      public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo "<p>custom widget appear</p>";
        echo "<p>". the_field('widget_banner') . "</p>";

} // outputs the content of the widget
        public function form( $instance ) {} // outputs the options form on admin
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {} // processes widget options to be saved
    }
    // register Foo_Widget widget
    function register_foo_widget() {
        register_widget( 'CustomWidget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );
```

строка `custom widget appear` выводится, а вот произвольное поле `the_field('widget_banner')` нет, хотя в админке оно есть, его заполняю и нажимаю сохранить и оно сохраняется

делаю [по образцу на форуме](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-and-widgets/), но у ребят в комментариях та же проблема

вот, что выводит в аргументах во фронтенде

```
array(10) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Виджеты" ["id"]=> string(9) "sidebar-1" ["description"]=> string(36) "Добавьте сюда блоки" ["class"]=> string(0) "" ["before_widget"]=> string(64) "
" ["after_widget"]=> string(8) "
" ["before_title"]=> string(4) "
" ["after_title"]=> string(5) "
" ["widget_id"]=> string(15) "custom_widget-2" ["widget_name"]=> string(12) "CustomWidget" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть описание по созданию Custom Widgets [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), для его вывода нужно еще создать `add_action()`

```
    add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
        register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
    });
```

У вас `widget`, `form` и `update` будет содержать определенный [код](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example)

Это ваш [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583385/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-wordpress/584030?noredirect=1#comment784036_584030)?
Там я объяснял как вывести

В виджете Вы можете вывести это поле или так:

```
    <?php the_field('widget_banner'); ?>
```

или так:

```
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'widget_banner', true) ?>
```

при условии, что Вы создали это поле `widget_banner`, которое привязано к `post_type -> post` и выводите его в цикле, смотрите пример на картинке (строка 69-70):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Админка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, забыл включить в описание - у меня этот блок тоже есть, но и с ним также ничего не выводит

Comment: Попробуйте сначала со статичным текстом, а потом уже будете выводить из CF, замените пока `the_field('widget_banner')` на статичный контент

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста описание внимательно - статичный контент выводит -  `echo "<p>custom widget appear</p>";` 
я об этом говорю

Comment: Да, извините не увидел. Значить виджет у вас работает, просто Вы неправильно передает в него параметры из CF

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, это же Вы ранее спрашивали по поводу вывода данных из Pods?

Comment: да, но я не знаю как это правильно сделать. про вывод данных из pods вероятно я спрашивал

Comment: ну тут сложно как-то ответить, во-первых вы создаете в ACF поле, которое закреплено неизвестно пока за чем (page, post), во-вторых вы же куда-то будете вставлять свою картинку, а выводить ее в виджете???

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48341/discussion-between-eugene-v-and-).